# Find largest number in a double array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a double array like this.

```
  double[] arr={1.5,10.9,8.9,6.5,10.0};
```

How can I want to find out the largest number amoung those array elements

I already have the basic logic

```
    public double getLargest(double[] arrray)
    {
        double largest = arrray[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arrray.Length;i++ )
        {
            if (arrray[i] > largest)
                largest = arrray[i];
        }
        return largest;
    }
```

I asked for a method like Math.max(); but Math.max() is not getting even I import System.Linq;  (It may be due to the reason that I am using framework 2.0)

Any way I did this method.

Comment: While I'd use `Enumerable.Max`, as pointed out in answers, it *will throw an Exception* on a sequence with 0-elements (which must be special-cased).

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek C# (and .NET 3.5+) is not Java (<= 7). Thankfully this basic stuff doesn't need to be written in such a barbaric fashion. (Not that I disagree with the sentiment of not showing effort.)

Comment: @user2864740 You won't understand how LINQ works unless you know how to use basic language features, e.g. loops. I would be really glad if he ask *here is `FindMax` method using `for` loop, how can I write it better?* instead of just posting a question like this one.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I was merely pointing out that, despite misgivings about the question, using a manual loop is a nonsense way to handle this task in most C# code.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Enumerable.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method

> Returns the maximum value in a sequence of values.

```
double[] arr = { 1.5, 10.9, 8.9, 6.5, 10.0 };
Console.WriteLine(arr.Max()); //10.9
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/7fkO5Q)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ, specifically the [`Enumerable.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var max = arr.Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is named `arr`

```
private double Biggest(double[] arr)
{
  if(arr != null && arr.Length > 0)
    return arr.Max();
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to be more elaborate

```
private double? Biggest(double[] arr)
{
  if(arr != null && arr.Length > 0)
    return arr.Max();
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I think a (mathematically) better return value for the empty array would be double.NegativeInfinity. =)

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`Enumerable.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It's an extension method, s you can use it like this:

```
double maximum = arr.Max();
```

This requires a `using System.Linq` statement at the top of the file though.

Comment: But when I do so I got the compile time error "The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) "

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file and ensure your are using .NET 3.5 or higher

Comment: @CaZban What version of .NET is it?

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the "simple" way to do it since I feel that is what the OP should learn first:

```
double max_value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] > max_value)
        max_value = arr[i];
}
```

Basic stuff, no need for fancy methods, max_value contains the maximum value after one pass of the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

```
double max=0;
foreach (double num in arr)
{
    if (num>max) {max=num;}
}
```

Comment: Is always a good practice to provide some explanation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using Linq:

```
double max_number = arr.Max();
```

To use Ling don't forget to include using System.Linq on top.